# How to use SBT to run ScalaTest tests against a fat jar?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, sbt-assembly

I have a simple SBT project, consisting of some Scala code in `src/main/scala` and some test code in `src/test/scala`. I use the `sbt-assembly` plugin to create a fat jar for deployment onto remote systems. The fat jar includes all the dependencies of the Scala project, including the Scala runtime itself. This all works great.

Now I'm trying to figure out a way I can run the Scala tests against the fat jar. I tried the obvious thing, creating a new config extending the `Test` config and modifying the `dependencyClasspath` to be the fat JAR instead of the default value, however this fails because (I assume because) the Scala runtime is included in the fat jar and collides somehow with the already-loaded Scala runtime.

My solution right now works but it has serious drawbacks. I just use `Fork.java` to invoke Java on the `org.scalatest.tools.Runner` runner with a classpath set to include the test code and the fat jar and all of the test dependencies. The downside is that none of the SBT test richness works, there's no `testQuick`, there's not `testOnly`, and the test failure reporting is on stdout.

My question boils down to this: how does one use SBT's test commands to run tests when those tests are dependent not on their corresponding SBT `compile` output, but on a fat JAR file which itself includes all the Scala runtimes?

Comment: Do you want to run tests before creating the uber jar?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No by the time the JAR has been created the tests have already passed by themselves.  The purpose of this test run is to verify they still pass when run against a fat jar.  That might sounds redundant but this fat jar will be post-processed by an optimizer and I need to verify the optimizer didn't break anything

Answer (score 1):

This is what I landed on (for specs2, but can be adapted). This is basically what you said was your Fork solution, but I figured I'd leave this here in case someone wanted to know what that might be. Unfortunately I don't think you can run this "officially" as a SBT test runner. I should also add that you still want Fork.java even though this is Scala, because Fork.scala depends on a runner class that I don't seem to have.

test.sbt (or build.sbt, if you want to put a bunch of stuff there - SBT reads all .sbt files in the root if you want to organize):

```
// Set up configuration for building a test assembly
Test / assembly / assemblyJarName := s"${name.value}-test-${version.value}.jar"
Test / assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := (assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy).value
Test / assembly / assemblyOption := (assembly / assemblyOption).value
Test / assembly / assemblyShadeRules := (assembly / assemblyShadeRules).value
Test / assembly / mainClass := Some("org.specs2.runner.files")
Test / test := {
  (Test / assembly).value

  val assembledFile: String = (Test / assembly / assemblyOutputPath).value.getAbsolutePath
  val minimalClasspath: Seq[String] = (Test / assembly / fullClasspath).value
    .filter(_.metadata.get(moduleID.key).get.organization.matches("^(org\\.(scala-lang|slf4j)|log4j).*"))
    .map(_.data.getAbsolutePath)

  val runClass: String = (Test / assembly / mainClass).value.get
  val classPath: Seq[String] = Seq(assembledFile) ++ minimalClasspath
  val args: Seq[String] = Seq("-cp", classPath.mkString(":"), runClass)

  val exitCode = Fork.java((Test / assembly / forkOptions).value, args)

  if (exitCode != 0) {
    throw new TestsFailedException()
  }
}
Test / assembly / test := {}
```

Change in build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(/* your original settings are here */)
  .settings(inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings): _*) // enable assembling in test
```